# Virtual Inheritance: Error: no unique final overrider

Tags: c++, overriding, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions, virtual-inheritance

I know virtual inheritance is covered here before and before asking this question, I went through the detail of the virtual inheritance and went through the details of a similar problem like the followings:

[multiple-diamond-inheritance-compiles-without-virtual-but-doesnt-with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219941/multiple-diamond-inheritance-compiles-without-virtual-but-doesnt-with) 
and 
[why does GCC give me an error - final overrider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712539/why-does-gcc-give-me-an-error-no-unique-final-overrider)

My problem is slightly different as I am not using pure virtual function and explicitly using virtual inheritance to have one unique `base` class. The hierarchy is as follows:

```
   base
    /\
   /  \
 der1 der2
   \  /
   der3
```

I know about the dreadful diamond on the derivation issue, and that's why I am using virtual inheritance.

```
#include <iostream>
class base
{
public :

    base()
    {
        std::cout<<"base()" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void fun()
    {
        std::cout<<"base" << std::endl;
    }
};

class der1: virtual public base
{
public :
    void fun()
    {
        std::cout<<"der1" << std::endl;
    }
};

class der2 : virtual public base
{
public :
    void fun()
    {
        std::cout<<"der2" << std::endl;
    }
};

class der3 : public der1,public der2
{
    public :
    /*void fun()
    {
        std::cout<<"der3" << std::endl;
    }*/
    //if I took out the comment and the function 
    //is defined it compiles fine as expected
};

int main()
{
    base *p=new der3;
    //used scope operation explicitly to avoid ambiguity
    p->base::fun(); //here it complains about 'no unique final overrider for fun'
    return 0;
}
```

My understanding is since I am using virtual inheritance, there should only be one instance of the `base,` and using the scope operator, I can invoke without ambiguity the virtual `fun` function. The function is not pure virtual. If I do leave an implementation on the `der3` class it is giving me a compiler error:

> error: no unique final override for ‘virtual void base::fun()’ in ‘der3’

I can see how this issue works ([final overrider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166926/virtual-multiple-inheritance-final-overrider)). But mine doesn't. Is it getting confused between `base::fun`, `der1::fun` and `der2::fun`? Does the scope operator help in any way?

Any clue or help is appreciated. I am using g++ 4.6.3.

Comment: I know why the above fails but I actually have a further question which is why I can't just put using der1::fun in der 3 and for it to then work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most-derived class has to provide an implementation of the virtual functions in the virtual base class - otherwise how would it provide that base class interface, given the intermediate classes (i.e. your `der1` and `der2`) provide two alternatives already - which one should it call?  You have to disambiguate the situation (i.e. with `der3::fun()`).

Sure you're not actually calling `der3::fun()` as you're explicitly requesting `base::fun()`, but that doesn't mean the rules don't apply, any more than thinking you could instantiate an abstract class if you don't try to call the pure-virtual functions....  The program is ill-formed until the code ties off these loose ends.

Comment: Thanks @Tony D so the bottom line is to have only one final overrider.

Comment: @jazaman: yes, per C++11 Standard 10.3/2 "In a derived class, if a virtual member function of a base class subobject has more than one final overrider the program is ill-formed."

Answer (score 10):

Using the scope resolution operator to specify that you want to call `base::fun` doesn't make the error go away because the program would be ill-formed even with an empty `main()`. You simply are not allowed to have a situation in which a virtual function has more than one final overrider in *any* derived class that exists in your program.

Informally, just because trying to call `p->fun()` *would* be ambiguous, the program is ill-formed even if you don't do it.

*Note*: This is in contrast to the situation you have with overloaded functions, in which potential ambiguity is allowed---perhaps even unavoidable---as long as you avoid a call that actually would be ambiguous. Why are the rules different? Basically it is because even constructing an object of type `der3` cannot be done in a sensible way---which version of `fun` should the vtable point to?

Comment: Thanks @Brian, Got that from the other answer. Do you have a standard reference about the final overrider?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have virtual inheritance, the object of type `der3` will only inherit one instance of `base`, i.e., it will not have two copies of `base` as it would without virtual inheritance. This means that `der3` can only have one `fun()` method. If the `fun()` method were not virtual then you would have copies of this method.

Since in your case there can be only one `fun()` method, inheriting two versions causes ambiguity. You either have to remove one of the `der1` or `der2` overrides of `fun()`, in order to resolve the ambiguity (`der3` will then inherit the one that is left), or you have to provide `der3`'s own version.