# C++ pseudo-diamond

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have searched for a similar question but found none. So I am sorry if a duplicate will occur because this looks like a common problem to me.

My question is very simple, consider the following:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void doit();
};

class B1 : public virtual A {
public:
 void doit();
};

class B2 : public virtual A {
public:
 void doit();
};

class C : public B1, public B2 {};
```

What happens if I do:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  C* el = new C();
  el->doit(); /* WHAT HAPPENS? */
}
```

Because the last class does not override the method, so it takes the method from parents... but which one does it select?

Comment: `#define override` is for doing what?

Comment: Just to stress the fact that I am overriding and make it clear... I can remove it if this is not helping...

Comment: 1. I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. 2. Using #define puts mud in the waters

Comment: `do` is a reserved keyword

Comment: For me your sample [simply doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a95ee00c5256dc7c), that's what happens.

Comment: @quantdev - And also a crap name for a function

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219941/multiple-diamond-inheritance-compiles-without-virtual-but-doesnt-with

Comment: @Andry and even after fixing the keyword problem mentioned by quantdev, [the code doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87aca8c33bf7f278)

Comment: After fixing all problems, it boils down to said question. See http://ideone.com/1YY7Q1

Comment: Yes, the original question solves everything. Thank you and sorry, I actually looked for this question, really did not find it :(